# Infinite loop in interceptor on catchError

Tags: angular

I have a jwt/refresh token authorization.

When `/api/auth/token/refresh` fails with a BadRequest due to refresh token not existance/expiration, I'm trying to catch the error through `catchError` and instead of throwing the error in the console log, I'm doing `next.handle(request)` to suppress the error. Currently, whenever the catchError comes, it runs in an infinite loop. In other words, after I catch the error, I want to `logout()` user, which executes an HTTP post request itself and then navigate to the login page.

The reason I'm doing `return this.authService.logout()` is because I have an HTTP post request in `logout()` and if I don't subscribe somehow, it won't execute it.

auth.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (error.status === 401) {
              return this.handleHttpResponseError(request, next);
            }
          }

          return throwError(error);
        })
      );
  }

  private handleHttpResponseError(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const accessToken = this.authService.getJwtToken();

    // if jwt token is not set, we just let the request execute
    if (!accessToken) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    // if jwt token has not expired yet, we add the authorize header
    // otherwise we refresh the token
    if (!this.authService.isTokenExpired()) {
      // add "Authorization: Bearer token" to the current request's headers
      return next.handle(this.attachTokenToRequest(request, accessToken));
    } else {
      // when the JWT token expires
      return this.authService.refreshToken()
        .pipe(
          switchMap(token => {
            console.log('Token refreshed.');
            return next.handle(this.attachTokenToRequest(request, token));
          }),
          catchError(error => {
            console.log('INFINITE LOOP HERE.');

            return this.authService.logout()
              .pipe(
                switchMap(error2 => {
                  console.log(error2);
                  this.router.navigate['/log-in'];
                  return next.handle(request);
                })
              );
          })
        );
    }
  }

  private attachTokenToRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  }
}


// auth.service.ts
logout() {
    return this.httpClient.post<AccessToken>(`${this.actionUrl}/token/revoke`, { 'refreshToken': this.getRefreshToken() })
      .pipe(
        map(() => {
          console.log('revoked token');

          localStorage.removeItem(this.JWT_TOKEN);
          localStorage.removeItem(this.REFRESH_TOKEN);
          return true;
        })
      );
}
```

Comment: Why is this confusing? The http request is failing I.e. `next.handle(request)` is throwing an error. You are intercepting this through catchError but then calling `next.handle(request)`.

Comment: I don't get it. Even if the last catchError returns `throwError(error)`, it does the infinite loop. The problem comes from `return.this.auth.logout()`.

Comment: handleHttpResponseError is calling `next.handle(request)` inside the catchError

Comment: @AndrewAllen, How am I supposed to handle it otherwise? The people here handled it likewise: https://github.com/IntertechInc/http-interceptor-refresh-token/blob/master/src/app/request-interceptor.service.ts

Comment: Try returning EMPTY.. `return EMPTY;` import from `import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: It is the same unless I replace `return this.authService.logout()` with something else.

Comment: @nop the example you give they are very careful, they re-request using a token first. If this fails they call `logoutUser()` which does not call `next.handle(request)`

Comment: I understand but how do I handle that?

Comment: Any idea how to deal with that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced to this problem and finally figure it out that it was because of a routing rule!

The problem was happening because i set `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` in app-routing.module.ts  so once i redirected page to login page from HttpErrorInterceptor class, the Interceptor was falling in an infinite loop.

So we have two choices to prevent happening this infinite loop:

- Removing `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'`

  Or
- Prevent happening multiple redirects with checking if it already is login page:
  So in the http-error.interceptor.ts file you can import `Router` and use a condition:

  ```
  if(this.router.url != '/login')
     this.router.navigate(["login"]);
  ```

It works for me and hope it could help others.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here for a similar issue: using `catchError` was retriggering the HTTP request infinitely. I hope my solution can help other people.

The problem is that I was using

```
// WRONG: causing an infinite retry loop
catchError((error, caught) => {
  // my logic here...
  return caught;
}),
```

and I did not get that returning `caught` again is actually a triggering **retry**.

So what I actually needed was instead:

```
// CORRECT
catchError((error) => {
  // my logic here...
  throw error;
}),
```